# Rewrite Rule Only Works With R Flag

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, joomla

I am stuck trying to work out why my rewrite rules will not work as internals, I do not want to change the url in the browser but if I remove the R I get an error.

The rewrites are to tidy up the get variables for 3 modules that I have written for joomla. Obviously I want the clean urls to stay in the browser and i have written the php to generate the links in this sef format. So I really need this rewrite to be internal and invisible to the end user.

From .htaccess

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1/ [L,R=301]

#Example /hire/audio/speakers/all
RewriteRule ^hire/([0-9a-zA-Z-&]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z-&]+)/all /section?section=$1&sub_section=$2&filter=1 [NC,L,R]

#Example /hire/audio/speakers/1
RewriteRule ^hire/([0-9a-zA-Z-&]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z-&]+)/(\d+) /section?section=$1&sub_section=$2&filter=$3 [NC,L,R]

#Example /hire/audio/speakers/jbl-jrx112m
RewriteRule ^hire/([0-9a-zA-Z-&]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z-&]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z-&]+) /detail?section=$1&sub_section=$2&product=$3 [NC,L,R]

#Example /hire/audio/speakers
RewriteRule ^hire/([0-9a-zA-Z-&]+)/([0-9a-zA-Z-&]+) /section?section=$1&sub_section=$2 [NC,L,R]

#Example /hire/audio
RewriteRule ^hire/([0-9a-zA-Z-&]+) /hire?section=$1 [NC,L,R]
```

Also is there any way to ensure that '&' is rewritten as %26 in the rewrite for the variable string data only leaving the & for the get variables in the url untouched? Eg:

/hire/audio/speakers/d&b-q7 = /detail?section=audio&sub_section=speakers&product=d%26b-q7

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Account-hopping …? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67194816/apache-mod-rewrite-help-please

Comment: I’d guess that `/section?…` and `/detail?…` probably need _additional_ rewriting, to actually map to some script or controller?

Comment: Hi CBroe, thanks for your reply. Not hopping, that is a post by the guy I asked to resolve it for me yesterday who came back and told me he couldn't get it to work without the R flag so I am picking it up from here. With reference to mapping any idea where I would find that information out in joomla? The page is an SP Pagebuilder page so I am guessing that they are both generated by the router. I asked SP Pagebuilder for any info on this before I asked David but they flat refused to give me any info.

Comment: With many of these CMS, their routing is based on simply rewriting everything to the index.php file - and then they evaluate `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']`, which does _not_ change due to internal rewrites via mod_rewrite, so it would still see the originally requested URL then. That would explain why it works, when you redirect externally. But doesn’t Joomla have a way to create “pretty” routes internally, via configuration?

Comment: I haven't been able to find anything on the internal routing. I would imagine that I would need to create a component to do that which seems a great deal of work when everything other than the url is working. I am really hoping someone will have a work around for the internal rewrite. I really am no expert but I am fast learning don't try to do something custom and then stick it in joomla...

Comment: The only workaround I can think of (_if_ what I described, is actually the issue here - which I expect it to be, WordPress for example handles this pretty much the same way), would be to rewrite this all to a custom PHP script of yours first, than can then _set_ `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` accordingly, and then requires the actual `index.php` after that.

Comment: If you want to go this way, probably makes sense to do a quick test first, to verify if it works: Create a `foo.php` in the root folder. In that, assign `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] = '/section?section=$1&sub_section=$2&filter=1';` (with sensible values in place of $1 and $2 of course, that lead to one specific piece of content), and then `require 'index.php';` after that. If you now call `/foo.php` in your browser, does it show the piece of content you intended?

Comment: Thanks so much for the info. It is now working!

Comment: @ChrisPrescott judging by your final comment, this page is doomed to be abandoned.  Please post your Joomla questions on [joomla.se] Stack Exchange and if you manage to resolve your problem you should endeavor to demonstrate this in a system-recognized way.  Please ask and self-answer your question in the most educational fashion that you can by posting on JSE.